# Delete all strings that are prefixes of another string

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering

I have a long list of strings and I'm trying to find a more efficient way of removing those elements that are prefixes of another:

```
example = {"Clothing", "Clothing/Accessories", "Clothing/Accessories/Belts", 
   "Watches", "Watches/Accessories", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}
```

This is what I have, but it is not very optimized:

```
DeleteCases[example, a_ /; Or @@ Table[
     StringStartsQ[b, a], {b, DeleteCases[example, a]}]]
```

> ```
>  {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}
> ```

My real example has 13,732 strings and it takes 292.156 seconds to pare it down to 11,372.

Comment: You could try `StringSplit` and work with `DeleteDuplicates` or similar from there.

Comment: What if there is a `"Watch"` string, should it be considered already included in `"Watches"` or should we only care about keys between `/` as a whole?

Answer (score 10):

Get the relation graph of your `example`

```
graph = SimpleGraph[RelationGraph[StringStartsQ, example], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Get the end of the vertex in every weaky connected graph

```
First@*TopologicalSort/@WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[graph]
```

> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}

Hope this can help. :)

Comment: +1 for pretty, but this will be *deadly* slow on a large list...

Comment: @ciao Good point out.Because of the `RelationGraph` is a bug function will result a ton wasteful computation.And I have reposted to *Wolfram Research* but get no response.

Answer (score 9):

Your solution doesn't seem to work when there are duplicates. Anyway, could you test the performance of the following method?

```
example =  RandomChoice[{"Clothing", "Clothing/Accessories", 
  "Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watch", "Watches/Accessories", 
  "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"
  },
  15000
];

Split[Sort@example,  StringStartsQ[#2, #] &][[;; , -1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0562741, 
>   {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}}
> ```

In case where you want to care about keys between `/` as a whole, e.g. `Watch` to not be considered within `Watches`, you can use:

```
StringStartsQ[#2 <> "/", # <> "/"]
```

instead of

```
StringStartsQ[#2, #]
```

Comment: It's 2.43905 seconds, much much better!

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: My original answer, while quite a bit quicker than the current answer, dropped some words that should not be dropped, *as does the other current answer*, e.g.. {"pa","paperweight"} fails on both (unless that is the intent of the OP, which I doubt).

This led me to the following, which does not suffer from the problem and is also quite a bit quicker yet:

```
dumpPrefixes2 = DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ Flatten@StringCases[#, (a : __ ~~ "/" :> a)]] &;
```

Usage:

```
dumpPrefixes2@yourList
```

Using

```
wrds = WordList[];

example = 
 Flatten@Table[
   NestList[StringJoin[{#, "/", RandomSample[wrds, 1]}] &, 
    RandomChoice[wrds], RandomChoice[{3, 2, 1} -> {0, 1, 2}]], 20000]
```

to generate a test set, seemed to perform well on loungebook, perhaps @kuba or you can test with your data on a real machine...

Comment: You mean that `pa` should not be considered included in `paperweight` because it's not up to `/`? That's why I've asked OP in a comment. Untill I get the answer I'm going hard merging :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Examples are like inventory items and categories, things like "watch" and "watchdog" then present a problem...

Comment: Yep. Added those cases handler too, can't test now but it seems that `StringStartsQ[#2 <> "/", # <> "/"]` should be enough.

Comment: p.s. there seem to be a problem with handling duplicates by `dumpPrefixes`, this `dumpPrefixes2@{"Watch", "Watch"}` returns the input. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Kuba - no, since OP did not specify behavior for duplicates, I did not remove them: goal was to be able to get result, and keep it stable (that is, *in the order of the target list*). Raises the question of what's to be done if duplicates are in list (they may not be), but trivially handled by a `DeleteDuplicates` pre/post operation. None of these may be issue for OP (and unless there are many lists or changing lists, who cares about performance?), I just found it an interesting tuning problem, posted idea.

Comment: I see, sure if the problem is not stated precisely then every interpretation is valid.

Comment: Yep - as you noted, OP example does not remove dupes, so who knows, but it *is* and interesting little puzzle, eh?

Comment: It is, I'm trying to do it association-style but failed to make it robust, not sure about the performance either. Something along those lines: `GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, 
  Function[list, If[Length[list] > 1, #0[list], list[[1, 1]]]]@*
   DeleteCases[{}]] &` will give `<|"Clothing" -> <|"Accessories" -> "Belts"|>, 
 "Watches" -> <|"Accessories" -> "Pocket Watch Chains"|>|>` (assuming we want to drop duplicates)

Answer (score 5):

```
Last /@ Gather[example, StringStartsQ[#2, #]&]
```

> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}

```
FileNameJoin /@ Last /@ Gather[FileNameSplit /@ example, SubsetQ[#2, #] &]
```

> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}

Also: slow but worth considering: a variation on @yode's approach

```
GraphComputation`SourceVertexList@SimpleGraph@RelationGraph[StringStartsQ, example]
```

> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch 
>   Chains"}

and

```
GeneralUtilities`GraphSources @ SimpleGraph @ RelationGraph[StringStartsQ, example]
```

> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch 
>   Chains"}

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[containerStrings]

containerStrings[stringList_] := Module[{TF, pos},
   TF = Outer[StringContainsQ, #, #]\[Transpose] &[stringList];
   pos = Position[Tally /@ TF, {{__}, {True, 1}}];
   Extract[stringList, pos]
]

containerStrings[example]
```

> ```
> {"Clothing/Accessories/Belts", "Watches/Accessories/Pocket Watch Chains"}
> ```

It is yet to be tested whether `Outer` is efficient for a large list of strings.